# What's the best key-value storage?

Tags: database, storage, key-value

Can you recommend a good key-value storage (e.g with great performance etc.)?

Comment: You must share more perspective for getting exact suggestion. Performance for what: reading or writing? You need cluster and / or transaction support? What is your max value size? There is no product for covring all performance indicator.

Comment: Please review the help section for a guide on which are [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) questions and which are [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked into [Redis](https://redis.io/) yet? I've used it on Pantheon platform, the experience was more than satisfactory.

> Redis is an open source (BSD licensed), in-memory data structure store, used as a database, cache and message broker. It supports data structures such as strings, hashes, lists, sets, sorted sets with range queries, bitmaps, hyperloglogs and geospatial indexes with radius queries. Redis has built-in replication, Lua scripting, LRU eviction, transactions and different levels of on-disk persistence, and provides high availability via Redis Sentinel and automatic partitioning with Redis Cluster. [Learn more →](https://redis.io/topics/introduction)

You may wanna check out the [Why We Recommend Redis as a Drupal or WordPress Caching Backend](https://pantheon.io/blog/why-we-recommend-redis-drupal-or-wordpress-caching-backend) article at Pantheon blog.